# Passthrough not working on Windows Unity Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, quest

My Windows passthrough build is not working at all inside Unity. I am using Oculus Quest VR device, Unity 2021.3.14f1 and while doing build, I have 0 errors reported.

I have followed every step for enabling it including:

- Importing OVRCameraRig,
- enabling passthrough in OVRManager,
- adding OVR Passthrough Layer and setting placement to Underlay,
- setting OVRPlugin to OpenXR inside Oculus->Tools->OVR Utilities Plugin tab,  • setting Developer runtime features and Pass-through over Oculus link inside Oculus application,
- setting Skybox material to none inside  Window->Rendering->Lighting->Environment
- everything that I found on the Internet, except that I am trying to do Windows .exe build.

Is it possible and supported to have pass-trough enabled on Windows platform and if yes, could you please provide steps to do so?